# Bind an event (click) to materialize Multi select

Tags: jquery, html, angular, materialize

I am having a problem to binding a click event to a [Materialize](http://materializecss.com) `Multi select` option in Angular 2.

I'm using the code code to fire an event in `ngAfterViewInit`. After intializing the Materialize Select using `$('select').material_select()` in `ngOnInit`

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    $('#gameList option[value="football"]').on('click',function(){
        console.log('Just fired')
    })
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <select id="gameList" multiple>
   <option value="cricket" selected="">Cricket</option>
   <option value="hockey">Hockey</option>
   <option value="football">Football</option>
   <option value="Baseball">Baseball</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This `#selectId` is not anywhere in your html. Do use

```
$('#gameList [value="football"]').on('click',function(){
     //whatever
})
```

Comment: I have already used it as in above code,By mistake I wrote slectedId instead gameList.